# Can't access fragment's method from activity - UninitializedPropertyAccessException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, anko

I have a `ViewPager`. I want to change page when fragment allow it to do.

This is the `onClick` when I want to check.

```
when (currentPage) {
   0 -> {
      if ((mAdapter.getItem(currentPage) as NameFragment).canGo()) {
         mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage + 1, true)
      }
   }
   1 -> ...
}
```

My Fragment:

```
private lateinit var fName: EditText
private lateinit var lName: EditText

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View = UI {
    verticalLayout {
       fName = editText {
          hint = "FIRST NAME"
          textSize = 20f
       }
       lName = editText {
          hint = "LAST NAME"
          textSize = 20f
       }
    }
}    

fun canGo(): Boolean {
   val firstName = fName.text.toString()
   val lastName = lName.text.toString()

   if (firstName.isEmpty() || firstName.isBlank() || lastName.isBlank() || lastName.isEmpty()) {
       toast("First name or Last name cannot be empty")
       return false
   }
   return true
}
```

I initialize `fName` and `lName` on `onCreateView` method and this is the error I get. Full exception is [here](https://gist.github.com/morhpt/ad7502640d03812514dc663b3279ab63).

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property fName has not been initialized
```

Comment: did you add the findviewbyid on the buttons ?

Comment: I don't need to. I use [Kotlin Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko).

Comment: What's the code for initialize the fname?

Answer (score 0):

These properties need to be initialised in the `onViewCreated` method, not `onCreateView`.

`onCreateView` is only responsible for creating the view as the name suggests, while `onViewCreated` is responsible for handling events after your fragment is properly created.

And if you need, you can create a callback that will be triggered when your fragment view is created, then you implement that callback in the activity, so that you will only access that `canGo` method after the fragment is created. Again, only if you really need to.

```
interface OnFragmentInflatedListener {
    fun onFragmentInflated(fragment: Fragment)
}

// Fragment
private var onFragmentInflatedListener: OnFragmentInflatedListener? = null

fun setOnFragmentInflatedListener(onFragmentInflatedListener: OnFragmentInflatedListener?) {
    this.onFragmentInflatedListener = onFragmentInflatedListener
}

// Fragment's onViewCreated
// initialise your properties here
onFragmentInflatedListener?.onFragmentInflated(this)

// Activity
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnFragmentInflatedListener {

    @Override
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        // do your stuff
        myFragment.setOnFragmentInflatedListener(this)
    }

    @Override
    fun onFragmentInflated(fragment: Fragment) {
        // do what you wanted to do
    }

}
```

Comment: I give my `EditText`s ids and initialized in the `onViewCreated`. Still getting the same error. Would you show me how to create a callback?

Comment: I'll edit the answer and then you accept it if it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd like to call my `canDo()` method when a button click on the `MyActivity`. I tried to call `myFragment.setOnFragmentInflatedListener(this)` when button clicks but it's not triggering the interface. It doesn't make sense to me. It already rendered. Why would it throw an UninitializedPropertyAccessException?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [this](https://learnpainless.com/android/how-to-get-fragment-from-viewpager-android) article. First I edited my `Adapter`:

```
private class Adapter(fm: FragmentManager, private val fragments: ArrayList<Fragment>) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
   private val instantiatedFragments = SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>>()

   override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = fragments[position]

   override fun getCount() = fragments.size

   override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any  {
     val fragment = super.instantiateItem(container, position) as Fragment
     instantiatedFragments.put(position, WeakReference(fragment))
     return fragment
   }

   @Nullable
   fun getFragment(position: Int) = instantiatedFragments.get(position)?.get()
}
```

And also my `onClick` method

```
when (currentPage) {
  0 -> {
     if ((mAdapter.getFragment(currentPage) as NameFragment).canGo()) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage + 1, true)
     }
  }
  1 -> ...
}
```

I changed `getItem(currentPage)` to `getFragment(currentPage)`.